# Wall.createcomment. Ошибка. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Использую метод wall.createcomment, но возникает ошибка:

```
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: could not access to this community
```

Токен получал разными способами!
И обычным (проставляя при этом все галочки), и через приложения(также давая все права), но ничего не меняется!.. Подскажите, что не так

Код:

```
import vk_api
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')
api = vk_session.get_api()
api.wall.createComment(owner_id='ID моей страницы, где как раз находится запись',
                   post_id='ID поста',
                   from_group='ID группы',
                   message='Комментарий')
```

Comment: А для чего используется id группы?

Comment: @Denis640Kb, для того, чтобы отправить комментарий от имени группы